# Matching regex groups in Java ignoring everything up until group is matched

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following strings:

`"# abcdef adase aff 0003fj22(1.20 (_rqa299302002_abcAbc_ABC)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file 4849jj22(4.1 (ABX_CDE)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file"`

`"0043jj22(1.20 (_rqa299333002_abcAbc_ABC)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file 48000dd21(4.1 (ABX_CDDE)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file 00632aa22(1.20 (_rqa299333002_abcAbc_ABC)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file 48003cd21(4.1 (ABX_CDDE)) - /path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file"`

My pattern that I have until now is the following:

```
(0{3}\\w*)(\\d+\\.\\d+)(\\(\\w*\\))(\\/.*)
```

What I want to match:

1. The first group I want to capture is for example `0043jj22`
2. the second group `1.20`
3. the third group is everything within the second bracket, e.g.
   `_rqa299333002_abcAbc_ABC` or `ABX_CDDE`
4. the fourth group is the path without `-`

But my pattern somehow doesn't match all groups.

1. The first cg: `0003fj22`
2. Second cg: `1.20`
3. Third cg: `_rqa299302002_abcAbc_ABC`
4. Fourth cg: `/path/to/some/random_dir/random - file/another_file/yet_another_file`

Comment: For each sample input, please show clearly what parts are to be captured as groups. For example, is `0003fj22` to be group 1 in the first sample input?

Comment: Thank you, i have hopefully now clarified everything.

Comment: I get a lot of these strings, the only thing they have in common is the structure unless they start with some random string like "# abcdef adase bsw " up until the 0043jj22 for example.

Comment: @heythere Please check my edit, I hope I didn't mess it up. Regarding your question, how about [`(\d\w*)\((\d+\.\d+)\s+\((\w*)\)+[\s-]+(/\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2REo/1) (regex101 demo).

Comment: Thank you! It's way more readable now. Your proposed regex unfortunately does not match the path completely. There is a "-" in the folder name which is why it only matches until "/path/to/some/random_dir/random"

Comment: Yw:) you meant the full `/path... - file/` [like this one](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2REo/2) not so clear. In the right side at the demo there is explanation. Just experiment a bit with it. Regex101 is a good playground to adjust pattern.